# How can I display the CLASSNAME in the log for PLAY Java?

Tags: java, logging, playframework-2.0

Why doesn't Play show/output the classname in the log?

Here's my logger config:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/application.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/debug_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="play" level="INFO" />
<logger name="application" level="INFO" />

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

My usage:

```
Logger.info("Attached shutdown hook for jedis pool.");
```

The output:

```
2014-05-22 15:28:39 - [info] application - Attached shutdown hook for jedis pool.
```

I wish it was more like:

```
2014-05-22 15:28:39 - [info] JedisManager - Attached shutdown hook for jedis pool.
```

How can I accomplish this?

In my application.conf:

```
application.secret=""
application.langs="en"

play {
  akka {
    loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger", "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-max = 36
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

db-context {
    fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 30
        parallelism-max = 30
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work. Have you tried to clean/reload/rebuild your project?

Comment: yep, i made sure that it reloaded everything. usually i run in debug mode, whenever i make some major changes(ie new files/configs) i would run "play clean idea run"

Answer (score 3):

Just define the predefined method in one static class like

```
public static void error(String data, String className) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
        logger.error(getClassNameAndLineNo(className)+ data); //log4j.logger

        play.Logger.error(data + getClassNameAndLineNo(className)); //play default logger
    }
```

and whenever you want to display log,just call the error method like this.

```
private static final String className =YourClassNameFromWhereYouAreCalling.class.getName();
className.error("msg",className);
```

because, the method is static method.so you can call by `ClassName.error();`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the logger configuration is not picked up. Try the following:

- make sure the logger configuration is called `logger.xml` or `application-logger.xml` and placed in the `conf/` directory of the application
- remove / comment out the logging instructions from `conf/application.conf`

Comment: yep, my logger.xml is place under /conf --> /conf/logger.xml. ive removed just about everything in the application.conf except for the secret key and some minor stuff. will update OP.

Comment: is there a log/application.log file being written at all? I don't see why the log configuration is not being picked up.

Comment: yep, i see similar outputs in both console and /log/application.log.. i even tried Logger.of(class_name)..

Comment: Try to explicitly pass the logger configuration to use as a JVM parameter (`-Dlogger.file=conf/logger.xml`). You can do so on linux or OS X by e.g. exporting `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` before running SBT, such as `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dlogger.file=conf/logger.xml`